# Populate a subreport from muti-valued combo box.

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I'm working on a simple database to organize some information for me. 
I have a table named "Units" which has a multivalue combobox for which weapons said unit can take. I am trying to populate a subreport on the report that displays the table for each item (weapon) that the unit can take.

Example

Unit 1

Weapons: Weapon1/Weapon2/Weapon3

Subreport:

### Weapon 1 table entries

### Weapon 2 table entries

### Weapon 3 table entries

I'm getting some minor success, my report is showing a separate entry for that unit and each weapon. Such as:

Unit 1

Subreport:

### Weapon 1

Unit 1

Subreport:

### Weapon 2

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly. Are you trying to group the entries? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-6a58e9ab-9f74-4689-83b6-c63cddb2c7f9

Comment: Table 1 has Primary key, some data, and then a combo box that you can select multiple items from.   Those items are primary keys from another table. I wish to make a report, that lists items in table 1, as well as the table for each selected item in the combo box.

Comment: OK, second try. My first answer being still valid - we're speaking about a report with groups. Now the easiest way to accomplish it: 1)Make a query in which you'll join all the tables involved and with all the fields to appear on the report. The query will also include a temporary table with the distinct values of the combo box 2) Use this query as datasource of your report. 3) Go back to my 1. answer and build up the groups as needed. PS: To get the distinct values of the combobox, you'll probably need to write an external VBA function.

Comment: Alrighty, I'll give it a go, thanks for the help! I'm still pretty green in access. Took a class in it and passed, but my experience is still lacking.

Comment: That's fine, we all started by trying.